# Youtube js API - seek backward in time not working

Tags: youtube-api

Seeking forward in time works.If I seekTo(160), for example, it works. But, if I try to seek backwards seekTo(30), it sets back to 160. This happens in opera,chrome; works like it should in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem has you described.
I don't know if it can help but I found out that after you query the API for the video duration, seek to previous location seemed to work...

I needed to do a "replay" kind of thing so what I've done is :

```
var duration = player.getDuration();
player.seekTo(duration-duration, false); // equals to video exact start time which should be the same as 0
player.playVideo();
```

My tests showed that doing

```
 player.seekTo(0, false);
```

was working after the duration has beed queried but I didn't wanted to take any chances :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
player.seekTo(duration, true);
```

Just set the `allowSeekAhead` value to `true` and it should work. It worked for me.